# Unable to generate token 'referer' must be specified

Tags: javascript, arcgis-online, arcgis-online-webmap, arcgis-api-wpf, token

I have created a HTML page which contains a feature layer that is published in the ArcGIS Online. The feature layer is shared with organization. When I run the page it is asking for the username and password, and whenever I enter the credentials it shows the username or password you entered is incorrect, but I know my username and password is absolutely correct.

When I checked in network, in generateToken file it gives error like: 
message: "Unable to generate token."
details: ["'referer' must be specified."]

And when I tried the same code in ArcGIS Online sandbox it worked fine.

Comment: The message is not about user name or password, it is about HTTP referer field https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer. Edit your code and add the missing header.

Comment: Which version of the ArcGIS API for JavaScript are you using in your HTML page?

Comment: Hi @BjornSvensson sorry for the late reply. I am using 3.31 version of ArcGIS API.

Comment: @user30184 sorry for late reply. Could you please tell me what to add in header or if you give me some example, i am new to ArcGIS API.

Comment: I am not familiar with the API but perhaps the documentation helps https://developers.arcgis.com/rest/users-groups-and-items/generate-token.htm

Comment: Thank you @user30184 for your reply.

Comment: have you find the solution ? i am facing the same issue.

Comment: @NehaSharma Run your code in the ArcGIS sandbox [https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/sandbox/sandbox.html] and when crentials are inserted in the login popup,that will get the referer.